# How to make Android toolbar shorter in terms of height

Tags: android

I'd like to make toolbar height relatively small. I tried to set minHeight but it doesn't work.

Thin green line is what I'd like to have as the toolbar but toolbar ignores minHeight so there's that red part around it.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        android:id="@+id/WindowTitleBar" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp" app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

            <View 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="5dp" 
                android:background="#00ff00"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Something" />
</LinearLayout>

public class TActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.t);

  Toolbar WindowTitleBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.WindowTitleBar);
  setSupportActionBar(WindowTitleBar);
 }
}
```

Of course, my toolbar will be more functional but this code illustrate the issue with height.

Note that I know that I could set layout_height to a fixed value but is there any more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What could possibly can be the solution other than setting height.

Just to clarify the attribute `minHeight` makes the `View` be at least this many pixels of height. So that's not gonna work with `TooBar`.For normal `ViewGroup` it will work.

So the solution is setting `android:layout_height` to predefined pixel.

Apart from that this will just just make `TooBar` useless. I mean a simple `View` can do that . The whole point of having `ToolBar` is to achieve material design and having menus and drawer indicator, Back, Title inside it .  If you want `ToolBar` as tall as the green line in your image then i think there is no use of having toolbar . You can simply use a `View`.

Answer (score 1):

I think setting the `layout_height` would be the best solution for your scenario. Maybe you could extract the toolbar layout to another xml to increase reusability and extract the height to `dimens.xml`. I can't think of a more elegant solution.

I hope it helps.